# Which is the authentic Hindu Calender?

Tags: time

Which Hindu calender is authentic ?

When is the first day of Hindu Calender ?

Comment: there is surya and chandra - mana calendars. different regions follow different panchang. ask your elders or local temple purohit

Comment: There are multiple calendars used by Hindu people, each considered authentic by their reckoners.